# how to show SE along with dots in a dot plot in Stata

Tags: stata, dot-plot

I want to make a dot plot with showing mean  and SE in the plot in Srara. But, I am not able to make the SEs in graph. Anyone has any example code to do that?  I have a continuous value in the y-axis and 6 variables type in my x-axis.

I have only used the code below:

```
dotplot val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 val6, mean
```

A reproducible data can be see as following:

```
clear
set obs 100
set seed 12345

forval j = 1/6 {
    gen val`j' = rnormal(`j' * 10, `j' * 2)
}

rename val1 baseline1
rename val2 vrs
rename val3 sgbd
rename val4 baseline2
rename val5 fdst
rename val6 sgvf
```

but I expect to get the SE in graph and also mean.

Comment: You could `collapse` to get a dataset of mean and SE of the mean. Then fire up `twoway scatter` and `twoway rcap` or `twoway rspike`. `dotplot` won't take you where you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some technique -- in the absence of a reproducible example from you.

```
clear 
set obs 100
set seed 314159 

forval j = 1/6 {
    gen val`j' = rnormal(`j', `j')
}

* you start here 
preserve 

forval j = 1/6 { 
    local call `call' (mean) mean`j'=val`j' (semean) semean`j'=val`j'
}

collapse `call'

gen id = 1 

reshape long mean semean, i(id) j(which)

gen upper = mean + se 
gen lower = mean - se 

twoway scatter mean which || rcap upper lower which, xla(1/6) ytitle(val) xtitle(which)

restore
```

EDIT

Making use of the reproducible example, here is some sample code.

```
clear
set obs 100
set seed 12345

forval j = 1/6 {
    gen val`j' = rnormal(`j' * 10, `j' * 2)
}

rename (val1-val6) (baseline1 vrs sgbd baseline2 fdst sgvf) 

* ssc install stripplot
stripplot baseline1-sgvf, bar(level(68)) stack ///
width(2) vertical msize(vsmall) ms(Sh)
```

Comment: thank you. but I would also like to get the observations (dots ) in the graph. Could you please modify so that I can have it?

Comment: See `stripplot` from SSC.

Comment: Could you please change your code so that works with stripplot? I could not make it to work. I appreciate it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example explains the standard here, namely self-contained questions with a reproducible example and a serious attempt at code.

Comment: Dear Nick Cox I have edited my question with the reproducible data to generate the data example. I hope it is fine, otherwise, please let me know. Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: thanks. probably my example is not a good one. However, is it possible to explain what does ? I should get mean and SE with dots in the graph. "stripplot baseline1-sgvf, bar(level(68)) stack ///
width(2) vertical msize(vsmall) ms(Sh)"

Comment: What is plotted is a 68% confidence interval for the mean, which should close to mean +/- SE of mean. For that sample size, the intervals are pretty short.